# Webdynpro - SALV Table, empty area below records keeps growing while scrolling horizontally - BUG?

Tags: alv, webdynpro

I have an salv-table inside viewcontaineruielement on my view.
It works as designed and the alv table is instantiated like this:

[image]

And my own config method does simply this:

[image]

BUT:

When I decide to scroll horizontally like this:

[image]

The "show no empty records" area grows and grows and grows which each scroll-click.

Why ? That's not what I want. Did I forget to set some config-variable ?

[image]